# Change the BA Server Fully Qualified URL in Pentaho Release 5.2.0.0.209

Tags: tomcat, server, pentaho

I'm trying to redirect Pentaho BA Server 5.2 to my domain. So, I have changed the following:

`context-param>
<param-name>fully-qualified-server-url</param-name>
<param-value>http://localhost:8080/pentaho/</param-value>
</context-param>`

By this

`<context-param>
<param-name>fully-qualified-server-url</param-name>
<param-value>https://mydomain/pentaho/</param-value>
</context-param>`

in the biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/web.xml file.
Then, I restart the BA Server. However, this doesn't go and when I log in Pentaho I'm redirected to http://localhost:8080/pentaho/index.jsp
I tried with other params values (e.g. 127.0.0.0:8080/pentaho/ , otherdomain/pentaho/, .....), but always I have the same result. I think that maybe Tomcat ignore this parameter and I don't know why it's happen.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Roberto Tardío

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cache from folder:

```
 1. Stop the server.
 2. biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\osgi\cache
 3. Restart the server.
```